# Why lock the QMutex at here?

Tags: qt

I'm reading Qt's [Blocking Fortune Client Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-blockingfortuneclient-example.html). There is a piece of code as below:

```
    mutex.lock();
    QString fortune;
    in >> fortune;
    emit newFortune(fortune);

    cond.wait(&mutex);
    serverName = hostName;
    serverPort = port;
    mutex.unlock();
```

I'm a bit confused why it lock the mutex at the first line. Because both **fortune** and **in** are local variables. Or the **emit** should be protected?

This is the code: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-blockingfortuneclient-fortunethread-cpp.html. The entire project can be found at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I don't see any reason to place the lock call to where it is placed. I'd put it right before the wait call. But I didn't thoroughly study the full example. You don't need to guard emit per se, though.

Comment: @ixSci: Thanks. here is the source code, http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-blockingfortuneclient-fortunethread-cpp.html, it's very short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the lock is placed in almost right place(I'd still place it after `in >> fortune;`).
Why it might need the `lock` before emit?

Emit happens in one thread while the slot gets executed in a different thread. So the following events might happen:

1. T1 emits the signal and gets suspended by the OS.
2. T2 gets the time quant and having received the signal it starts executing the slot(`showFortune`)
3. If `nextFortune == currentFortune` is true then thread's `requestNewFortune` gets executed in the T2 context.
4. `requestNewFortune` trying to lock mutex but fails and gets suspended.
5. T1 gets resumed and proceed until `cond.wait` when it releases the mutex and gets suspended
6. Since mutex is released T2 gets resumed and executes its code which ends up with `cond.wakeOne`
7. T1 gets resumed by the `wakeOne` call and finishes its code correctly.

What if we didn't lock the mutex before the emit call? We could end up with step #4 executed like

> execute its code which ends up with `cond.wakeOne`

and this `wakeOne` would be lost forever and when T1 would get to `cond.wait` it would not be resumed since the `wakeOne` call it awaits is lost.